# Map Parallels shared folder to drive letter

Tags: macos, unix, parallels-desktop

I'm running Parallels 9 for Mac (OS X 10.9) and I have CentOS Linux (6.4) installed.

I want to map a shared folder from my Mac to a drive letter in CentOS.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS (like all Linux distros) doesn't have "drive letters" - that is a throwback to the toy operating systems that were installed on some computers in the 1990's and early this century. I believe they went by the name "Windows".

Instead it uses mount points.

Once you have installed the Parallels tools you can use the "Shared Folders Tool" to specify the mount point for the folders that are being shared from your Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Parallels only lets me specify the folder with a path ~/Desktop/Parallels Shared Folders/MyFolder in my Linux VM.  I don't see any options from Parallels that let me rename this folder to something shorter and let me put in ~/ rather than ~/Desktop.

Comment: The answer to that might be to create a link from where you are forced to put it to where you want it. Check out `man ln`